# UIWebView does not load the URL

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have very small problem while loading the **URL** in `UIWebView`. 
I have one `UIButton`, on clicking of it, I add the `UIView` which contains `UIWebView`, `UIButton` & `Title bar`. Code used is as follows -

```
    [self.view addSubview:vwOnline];
    vwOnline.bounds = self.view.bounds;

    //Load webview
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", objWine.strOnlineURL]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [wbvwOnline loadRequest:request];

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //Show activity indicator
    [indicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //Remove Activity indicator
    [indicator stopAnimating];
    [indicator removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Find A Vino" message:@"Error while loading request." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    alert.tag = 1;

    //Remove Activity indicator
    [indicator stopAnimating];
    [indicator removeFromSuperview];
}
```

By doing above code, most of times the `UIWebView` does not loads the `URL` which I passed in the object `objWine.strOnlineURL`. If I clicked the back button & again clicked on the button to load the `URL`, it goes into the `- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` delegate method of `UIWebView`.
If anyone knows the solution, then please help me.

Comment: Is the contents of objWine.strOnlineURL definitely a valid url?

Comment: yes the contents are valid because if I copy & paste that contains on browser, then it opens that URL on browser.

Comment: What does gets printed to NSLog(@"Error ... ?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: @NikitaP Error - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding your `webview` on your `button` click each time. Why don't you add your `webview` into your `viewDidLoad` and `hide` and `show` it in your `button` click.

Answer (score 1):

when  you are going back, make request to nil and load empty `htmlstring` to `webview`. One more thing, remove `[indicator removeFromSuperview];` line from

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error 
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

if it is work fine then check `objWine.strOnlineURL`

otherwise it is clear :)

Comment: For google also it gives error if I open url & back 2-3 times.