# uiwebview screen appear to white and webview stop working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

i am getting below error and webview appear to be white and stop working anymore. when trying to uploading image on site .

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0xaa18300 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.livebinders.com/images/icons/wait30trans.gif, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.livebinders.com/images/icons/wait30trans.gif}
```

actually i am getting this error when i share url on "www.livebinders.com" site. for sharing url i hit a different link. after sharing url on site when i am uploading image on "www.livebinders.com". my webview appear to white and webview stop working any more. when i go back to home screen and then i come to webview screen it still appear to be white.

// this code i am using to share url on site

```
-(void) loadLivebinderItTool:(NSString *)url{
    NSLog(@"url string %@",url);
    //[_overlayView removeFromSuperview];

    [_webView stopLoading];
    NSString *urlLink;//media/add_url_to_binder

    urlLink = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@&description=image",BASE_URL_STRING,UPLOAD_SINGLE_URL, url];

    NSLog(@"url manager :%@", urlLink);
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlLink]];

    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

and this code i am using to upload image on site

```
-(void) loadDirectAttachView:(NSString *)data{
    NSLog(@"data string %@",data);
    [_overlayView removeFromSuperview];
    [_overlayView setHidden:YES];
    NSRange isRange = [data rangeOfString:@"Error" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(isRange.location == 0) {
        [_webView reload];
        [Common showAlert:@"Error" message:data];
       // [self loadSelectedView ];
        return;
    }

    NSArray *codeArray = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *code = [codeArray objectAtIndex:codeArray.count-1];
    code = [code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    //code= @"MTQ1Mzc4Mg==";
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataFromBase64String:code];
    NSString *convertedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"converted string %@",convertedString);
   [_webView stopLoading];
    NSString *urlLink;
    NSLog(@"converted string value %@",convertedString);
    urlLink = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@&description=write_here",BASE_URL_STRING,UPLOAD_SINGLE_MANAGER_URL, convertedString];

    NSLog(@"url manager :%@", urlLink);

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlLink]];

    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

after uploading image successfully on site it call this operation completed method

```
-(void) operationCompleted:(NSString*) data
{

    NSLog(@"after completion: %@",data);

     [_overlayView removeFromSuperview];
    [_overlayView setHidden:YES];

    if (_webView) {
         [_webView reload];
    }

        NSRange isRange = [data rangeOfString:@"Error" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(isRange.location == 0) {
            [Common showAlert:@"Error" message:data];
    }

}
```

i have found that problem occur in operationCompleted: method . because when it called [_webView reload]; then issue this issue occur and webview screen appear as white and webview stop working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256484/uiwebview-does-not-load-the-url use this